# running protractor tests with --suite option does not execute the control script

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, test-suite

I've followed the http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects to set up test suites

and I only have added the following to the previously running protractor.config.js

```
 suites: {
    option1: './e2e/e2e-option1_page-spec.ts',
    option2: './e2e/e2e-option2_page-spec.ts'
  },
```

when I run protractor protractor.config.js 
both options are running successfully

when I run protractor protractor.config.js --suite option1 or protractor.config.js --suite option2

following happens:

```
>$ protractor protractor.conf.js --suite option1
[10:56:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:56:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Jasmine started

>Executed 0 of 0 specs SUCCESS in 0.003 sec.
```

what am I missing?

---

update: I'm using TypeScript

Comment: You have given the path for `.ts` files instead of `.js` files. Modify the spec file paths with the compiled file path and try it again!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. 

all my files are  .ts

Comment: I've just set this up again and it seems to be fully working now. 
I've done exactly the same thing as I described in the issue

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be fully working now.

not sure where the failure was.

I've set this up exactly as I described in the issue and all options are working well now

Answer (score -1):

Try to run tests this way:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js -- --suite option1
```

Comment: this statement throws "Error: Error: more than one config file specified"